# Get target device by /dev/dm-X entry

Tags: linux, loop-device, device-mapper

I have to map several loopback devices via `dmsetup`.

I could track which loopback device is mapped to a particular `/dev/dm-X` device file, but is there an easy way to get this info by the `/dev/dm-X` itself?

`dmsetup info` was of no help for me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constituent devices are under `/sys/block/dm-X/slaves`. E.g.,

```
$ ls /sys/block/dm-2/slaves/
loop0
```